# Как задать @Html.EditorFor для даты?

Tags: html, c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap, razor

Есть страница:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.EditVM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<body>
<h3>Редактирование графика работы по элементу содержания</h3>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">        
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2">Количество выделенных часов:</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control">
        </div>       
    </div>
}
</body>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**1.** И первый вопрос сразу: у меня никак не получилось выравнить `label` и `input`. `label` как видите немного опущен. Как их выравнить?

Но это не основной вопрос. Мне необходимо вместо `input` использовать хелпер, чтобы привязаться к полю модели и вот как я это делаю:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Количество выделенных часов:</label>
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.PlanOO.HoursDateStart, new { @class = "form-control" })
 </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**2.** Теперь поле стало "не красивым, превратилось в некий 2d формат)".

**3.** и оно теперь не формата `DateTime`

Что можно предпринять по этим 3-м пунктам?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить к проперти модели:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

Comment: спасибо. А есть ли предложение по первому вопросу?

Comment: Задать лабелу хотя бы col-md-5, а инпут обернуть в div c class="col-md-6" например.